# Apache and sharing media in a separate directory

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am building a django app that runs out of my /Users/me/Dropbox directory.

Localhost is pointed at my /Users/me/Sites directory.

mod_wsgi installed.
apache installed
django installed and app working fine in development mode

I am trying to embed media in a template
This media comes from a directory outside of the django app - in the root of the machine - /PROYECTOS

The permissions for the directories and preceding directories are readable by _www

I think that I understand that

- mod_wsgi will serve the dynamic files
- apache will serve the static files like the css and template files, as well as the media files I am referencing in the /PROYECTOS directory

I have the following in my settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE, "static"), )
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/PROYECTOS/"
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mbrain.wsgi.application'
```

In the /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/localhost.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/localhost"
ServerName localhost

WSGIDaemonProcess localhost python-path=/Users/me/Dropbox/mBrain_Adam/mbrain/:/Users/me/Dropbox/mBrain_Adam/mbrain/venv/include/python2.7
WSGIProcessGroup localhost

Alias /proyectos/ /PROYECTOS/

<Directory /PROYECTOS>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/me/Dropbox/mBrain_Adam/mbrain/mbrain/wsgi.py

<Directory /Users/me/Dropbox/mBrain_Adam/mbrain/mbrain>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

So to embed a media file in a template I have this as the url:
{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ asset.assetPath }}

When I load the page in a browser the console shows the fully expanded path for the media asset but with a 404 error - HTTP/1.1" 404 3045.

I’d really appreciate any feedback on whether I am approaching this the right way or if I have completely missed the concept.
Also any help on that 404 error would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you remove the trailing slash? 
Alias /proyectos /PROYECTOS

Comment: I shall give that a go, but I would have thought that any additional slashes wouldn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect.